# Serializing F# Record type to JSON includes '@' character after each property

Tags: json, f#

The DataContractJsonSerializer creates JSON for F# record types that includes the '@' character after each property name. Does anyone know if it is possible to get JSON that does not have this trailing at symbol?

```
{"heart_rate@":20,"latitude@":45.0,"longitude@":108.0,"name@":"Rambo"}
```

Here is the script I use to output this sample

```
#r "System.Xml"
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"

open System.Text
open System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
open System.IO

type Update = {
    name: string;
    latitude: decimal;
    longitude: decimal;
    heart_rate: int}

let update = {name = "Rambo"; latitude = 45.0m; longitude = 108.0m; heart_rate = 20}

let serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof<Update> )

let stream = new MemoryStream()
let data = serializer.WriteObject(stream, update)
let updateData = stream.ToArray()

let json = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(updateData))

printfn "%s" json
```

Comment: FWIW, here's how I make it work in ASP.NET Web API: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/15/easy-aspnet-web-api-dtos-with-f-climutable-records

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although Daniel's solution will work correctly, it is rather tedious to have to add attributes to every property in the record. It turns out that Json.NET produces more readable JSON out of the box. For my application I do not need to use the DataContractSerializer specifically, so JSON.net it is!

Comment: Json.Net appends `@` for me as well. So only Daniel's solution solved the problem.

Comment: @abatishchev What version of Json.NET did you try? Support was added for F# in 6. I imagine if you were using a version previous to that it wouldn't work well.

Comment: @Kazark: if I remember correctly, it was 6.0.x, so even with "F# support" it didn't work well for me.

Comment: Json.Net 'just works', however in Web API it's bindings are overridden by a System.Net.Http class, which doesn't. You *can* set them back to the Newtonsoft defaults however: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26036775/26167

Answer (score 14):

It's using the name of the compiler generated backing fields. You can use `DataMemberAttribute` to provide your own names.

```
[<DataContract>]
type Update = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name="name")>]
    name: string;
    [<field: DataMember(Name="latitude")>]
    latitude: decimal;
    [<field: DataMember(Name="longitude")>]
    longitude: decimal;
    [<field: DataMember(Name="heart_rate")>]
    heart_rate: int}
```