# Return an F# record type as JSON in Azure Functions

Tags: json, azure, f#, azure-functions

I'm creating a simple azure function in F#. At the end, I'm returning a record type as JSON. I'm doing something like this:

```
let y = {Gender = "Woman"; Frequency = 17; Percentage = 100.0}
req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, y);
```

When I call the function from Postman I'm getting this JSON
`{"Gender@":"Woman","Frequency@":17,"Percentage@":100}`

It looks like that this is caused by the default serializer ([Serializing F# Record type to JSON includes '@' character after each property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037472/serializing-f-record-type-to-json-includes-character-after-each-property)).

Then I tried to use Newtonsoft.Json. Now, the code looks like this:

```
req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y));
```

But now I'm getting this using postman:

```
"{\"Gender\":\"Woman\",\"Frequency\":17,\"Percentage\":100}"
```

I'd like to get this response:
`{"Gender":"Woman","Frequency":17,"Percentage":100}`

How can I get this JSON response? Is there any other way apart from specifying `DataMemberAttribute`?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like CreateResponse is converting your newton string into a json string again. Try forcing the media type to "text/plain" in CreateResponse().

Comment: Magic! Thank you very much! If you want to create an answer I'll approve it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use JSON.Net (would be nice) because the AzureFunctions infrastructure seems to the Data Contract Serializers

I have just implemented the fix as per [Serializing F# Record type to JSON includes '@' character after each property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037901/1180200) and it works for me if a bit clunkier than you may hope.

I was also struggling to fix this and you got me going in the right direction - Thanks

```
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"

open System.Runtime.Serialization

[<DataContract>]
type SearchItem = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name="Gender")>]
    Gender: string
    [<field: DataMember(Name="Frequency")>]
    Frequency: int
    [<field: DataMember(Name="Percentage")>]
    Percentage: float
}
```

Comment: Please, see @ray comment to my original question.

Comment: Then you have a text/plain response which makes the content type a bit pointless. What if they don't accept/want text/plain. For my project I think we're going to use the attributes - a small price to pay and then we don't have the extra JSON code and leverage F# type safety

Comment: I agree, the DataMember attribute seems the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a super simple way to fix this!

There is an overload to `req.CreateResponse()` that takes a `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` as a 3rd parameter. This allows us to set the `ContractResolver` to one provided by Json.Net.

```
let jsonFormatter = System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <- Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()

return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, { Foo = "Bar" }, jsonFormatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % to why you get that response, I think it is because you are actually taking the string of an object and not the actual string. If you do this it will work (I think):

```
let response = sprintf "%s" JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y)
req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same response. I'm doing:
```
let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(y)
let jsonResponse = sprintf "%s" json
req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonResponse)
```

(I don't know why I get a compilation error if I use a single line getting the jsonResponse string)

Comment: Thanks for your help Tomas. @ray proposed solution worked for me.